# Replace text when in visual-block mode

Tags: vim, find-and-replace, text-editing

Maybe I'm searching the wrong way, but I've failed to find out how to do this.

Here's the scenario: I have a list in a text file where I want to insert the same word on multiple lines, here's an example text:

```
12.1           Item1
12.2           Item2
12.3           Item3
```

Now I visual-block mark the 8th column, indicated with underscores below, and intend to replace part of the whitespace with `Done` without moving the item column:

```
12.1   _       Item1
12.2   _       Item2
12.3   _       Item3
```

I expected that I could go into replace mode, but I can only enter insert (`I`), append (`A`), or change-mode (`c`). The change-mode comes close to what I want: if I know the length of the word the block can be set to the same width.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why don't you select 4 columns and hit `c`?

```
<C-v>
2j
3l
cDone
<Esc>
```

Also, you could use `:h normal`:

```
V
2j
:'<,'>norm 7lRDone
<Esc>
```

Comment: That works for `Done`, but what if I want to write something else, I want to be free from counting characters, if possible.

Comment: `:norm` is your friend, then.

Comment: Yes the second solution can be used for a convenient mapping. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to substitute within a visual block, you can use the [`vis.vim` plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS).

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Applying_substitutes_to_a_visual_block

To install:

Download vis.vba.gz from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS

```
# Open vis.vba.gz in Vim 7.1 or later.
vim vis.vba.gz

# Source the open file.
:so %

# Quit Vim
:q
```

Once installed:

```
ctrl-v to enter visual-block mode
Move to select the block you want
:B s/pattern/newtext/
```

Even better, you can perform any Ex command on the visual block, not just substitutions. For example `:B !sort`.

Comment: Nice plugin, I will be using it :-). But how can I use it to replace arbitrary columns?

Comment: Right, you still have the problem of quickly setting the visual block width to match your arbitrary-width columns. I usually do <count> `w` or `e` to select several columns quickly, then adjust with `h` or `l`.